# Issue with Port Forwarding in Kali

Tags: kali-linux, port-forwarding

I am new to hacking, I am trying to hack android over WAN but I can't seem to figure out how to open port 4444 on my IP. I opened it from my router settings but when I go to canyouseeme.org it says connection refused. I run "nc -l -p 4444" in terminal but it opens port for a few seconds. How do I do it, any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is not a security question, but an OS question about opening ports. You seem to be asking about running a service on a particular port.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some basic knowledge about the scenario you're trying to apply, here is some ideas:

First, you have to understand what is reverse and bind connections, that will help you to know what's the meaning of `open a port` on your machine.

- Bind connection: when you initialize the connection to a remote server that's **listening and waiting** for a connection.
- Reverse connection: when you **start a listener** and wait other clients to connect to your machine. "and that's what you're trying to do".

Second, there's a difference between working on LAN and WAN:

- On LAN: the victim and your machine are on the same network or subnet, so you can start the listener so the connection happens locally. For example: listener on 192.168.1.10/24 and victim on 192.168.10.125/24.
- On WAN: in general you can't start the listener on a private network and wait for victims from outside your subnet, so you must **use forwarding** between your public and private IP. it means that the victim connects to your public IP, then your router forwards it to the attacking machine.

So, to get started, I recommend to understand that, and try to apply it on a local network at first, then you can move to WAN networks.